# Sculpting brush behaves weirdly

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I am still a beginner and I am trying to sculpt a character. However, I faced a problem with the brushes.

Suddenly, the brushes do not fill up the creased places and will not smooth out the surface. I am not sure if I pressed something wrong as it worked just fine before.

The first image is before a stroke and the second image is after a one continuous stroke. The creased spaces won't fill up and creates weird textures.

I hope this made sense and help me if anyone has a solution to this issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE! As a workaround, I would suggest the following: 1. Move your sculpt (and any other important objects/collections in your project) into a new collection called "Master", and save your file. 2. Start a new blender project. 3. Go to *File > Append*. Browse to and select your previously saved file with the "Master" collection. 4. Go to Collection and append the "Master" collection from your original file. - You should now have access to your original sculpt, but all of the brushes should behave as they do by default. Don't forget to save this new project.